# Git repo subfolder as subtree of another repo?

Tags: git, github

My company is working on migrating from SVN to Git - part of the reason is to take advantage of deployment software that works using Git as a source. We're using a single repository (monorepo) for all components of our application stack.

We're also looking at using PM2 for NodeJS app management/deployment. Since this can use a git repository for deploying updates, we'd love to use it - but only a single subdirectory of our repository is really needed to be deployed.

**Is it possible to create a git repository that references just a single subdirectory of another git repo as a submodule / subtree?**

Something like this - with Repo A being the main monorepo and Repo B being the repo containing only the NodeJS stuff from Repo A.

```
RepoA\
  Component1\
  Component2\
  DelphiApp\
  NodeJSApp\
  PHPStuff\
  Configurations\
  Utilities\
```

```
RepoB\
  NodeJSApp\ <--subtree/submodule back to NodeJSApp in RepoA
```

Answer (score 0):

For `git submodule`, the short answer is no:

- You either have a repository or you don't.

  - If you don't have the repository, you can clone it, and now you do.  But you have the *repository*, not some subdirectory *of* the repository.
- Now that you do have the repository, you either have some commit in it, or you don't.

  (Commits are identified by hash IDs—those big ugly strings of letters and numbers—and since humans are bad at remembering random strings of letters-and-numbers, and for other purposes, each repository has some set of *names* that each remember one hash ID.  The names are good for *you*, but what Git *really* needs is the hash ID.)

  - If you don't have the commit, you can have your Git connect to another Git that also has the repository.  Your Git can ask their Git about commits that they have, that you don't, and get those commits into your Git repository.  Now, if they have the commit, so do you.
- Now that you have the repository and the commit, you have *all* the files.  A commit is (or more precisely, contains / refers-to and obtains) a complete snapshot of *every* file.

You don't have to *use* all the files.  You can extract only the files you care about.  But that's a lot harder than just using `git checkout name` to get the commit whose hash ID is stored in name *`name`*, which gets you *all* the files.  The easier way to go is probably the way to go.

#### Other options

Note that Git has various procedures for dealing with subtrees.  Some of them are captured into a contributed script called `git subtree`, for which there is a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec) that seems OK (at a quick glance).  Using `git subtree` to split out the library now and then *can* get you just what you want.  I don't recommend using subtrees in general though—it's better to split "library-like" code into a completely separate repository.

You can then either use multiple independent repositories, which is pretty simple to do, or use [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to select particular commits from the "library" repository, in either the "using-library" repository that has all the rest of the code, or in a "gets-submodules-only" superproject that has both the using-the-library and providing-the-library repositories as its (now two) submodules.  That is, you either have:

- superproject: contains `Component1/*`, `Component2/*`, `DelphiApp/*`, `PHPStuff/*`, `Configurations/*`, and `Utilities/*`, and *refers to* a submodule `NodeJSApp/`, plus
- library: contains files `*` that will live in a `NodeJSApp/` directory as controlled by the superproject

Or, you have:

- superproject: *refers to* a submodule `app/`, and *refers to* a submodule `app/NodeJSApp/`
- app: a Git repository containing `Component1/*`, `Component2/*`, etc., but does not refer to `NodeJSApp/` at all.  The superproject will extract these to `app/` so that their full names will be `app/Component1/*`, `app/Component2/*`, etc.
- library: a Git repository containing files named `*` that make up the library.  The superproject will extract these to `app/NodeJSApp/` so that their full names will be `app/NodeJSApp/*`.

The only difference between these, besides being forced to find everything under `app/` for the second approach, is that with the second approach, you'll manage the two independent Git repositories—one for the app itself, and one for the library—independently, then use the superproject to say: *build the project by extracting hash<sub>app</sub> from the app Git repository, and hash<sub>lib</sub> from the library Git repository.*  That is, *neither* subproject needs to be aware of Git-ness and hash IDs: only the *superproject* has to care about that.

With the first approach, you eliminate the need for the `app/` top level directory, but now every commit you make *in* the main app records a hash ID that Git should extract in the library submodule before you build.  If you update the library, you then need to record the new hash ID in the superproject.  This is the same as before, except "the superproject" *is* **the app itself**, rather than a third Git repository that merely contains the two submodule references.

The two-Git-repositories, one that has files *and* acts as superproject to pick out a particular commit in the submodule, is the more common approach.  It's sometimes more convenient.  The "one superproject to supervise everything else" method sometimes makes more *sense*, but it's definitely less common.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. Just do not use submodules. subtree or subrepo can help you there. You can make the 'NodeJSapp' a subtree or a subrepo in repoA. It will efficiently map the directory to the corresponding one-directory repository.

This way you'd be able to use repo A as a main one with atomic operations, like branching, across the whole tree, including the NodeJSApp directory. You would need to push and pull it periodically into RepoB. Submodules do not work this way. Subtrees do, but in some limited facion. Subrepos could be the best available opensource choice.

There are custom ways to do it as well.